# Flask-WTF: multiple forms of same class all returning the same data on submission

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I'm generating multiple forms, one per image, and packaging the image and corresponding form as a tuple in a list.

This list is then passed to Jinja where each tuple is unpacked and each image and form are inserted into a list for voting via the form.

My issue is that clicking on any one of the specific forms causes all form to return as if that button was clicked.

So, in effect, up or down voting one image acts as if that button was clicked for all other images.

I know I am creating legitimate forms as I have tried printing the form and it's return data to console.  When I do this, each form does have a unique address, and all forms show the same data (True / False) in the form.field.data attribute.
Can somebody help me discover what's going on here?

Form:

```
class VoteForm(FlaskForm):
    upvote = SubmitField('vote up')
    downvote = SubmitField('vote down')
```

Route:

```
@index_mod.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    pics = Pic.select().order_by(Pic.score.desc())

    pics_and_forms = []

    for pic in pics:
        voteform = VoteForm()
        #tuple of pic and corresponding form
        pics_and_forms.append( (pic, voteform) )

    for pic, form in pics_and_forms:
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            if form.upvote.data:
                pic.score += 1
                pic.save()
            if form.downvote.data:
                pic.score -= 1
                pic.save()              

    return render_template('index.html', pics_and_forms = pics_and_forms)
```

Jinja:

```
<ul>
    {% for pic, form in pics_and_forms %}
    <li>
        <b>{{ pic.name }}  </b>
        <i>Submitted by {{ pic.user.username }}</i>
        Score: {{ pic.score }}
        <img src="/pic/get/{{ pic.uuid }}" style="width:128px;" >

        <form method="post" action=" {{ url_for('index_mod.index') }}">
        {{ form.csrf_token }}
        {{ form.upvote }}
        {{ form.downvote }}
        </form>

    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

**EDIT**

So I'm figuring out that while I can embed as many forms onto the page as I want the returning post request doesn't specify which specific form was clicked.

Instead I'm planning to embed the details into a hidden field and then use the flask request object to retrieve that field from the hidden form.

I would rather use Flask-WTF fully for this but it seems like there's no elegant way to dynamically add multiple forms to a page and retrieve which form was actually clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You're only ever submitting one form at a time, so you really only need to be dealing with one Form object. I think a better approach would be to POST to a URL which contains the ID of the Pic you're voting on, and the up/down vote is captured from the submit button clicked.

I've refactored your code to illustrate this:

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import SubmitField


app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'secret'


class VoteForm(FlaskForm):
    upvote = SubmitField('vote up')
    downvote = SubmitField('vote down')


@app.route("/", methods=['GET'])
def index():

    form = VoteForm()

    pics = [
        {
            "name": "test",
            "user": {"username": "test"},
            "score": 1,
            "uuid": 'test'
        },
        {
            "name": "test2",
            "user": {"username": "test"},
            "score": 2,
            "uuid": 'test2'
        }
    ]

    return render_template("index.html", form=form, pics=pics)


@app.route("/pic/<id>/vote", methods=['POST'])
def vote(id):

    form = VoteForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if form.upvote.data:
            print("Upvote for pic {}".format(id))
        if form.downvote.data:
            print("Downvote for pic {}".format(id))

    return redirect(url_for('index'))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**index.html**

```
<ul>
    {% for pic in pics %}
    <li>
        <b>{{ pic.name }}  </b>
        <i>Submitted by {{ pic.user.username }}</i>
        Score: {{ pic.score }}
        <img src="/pic/get/{{ pic.uuid }}" style="width:128px;" >

        <form method="post" action="{{ url_for('vote', id=pic['uuid']) }}">
        {{ form.csrf_token }}
        {{ form.upvote }}
        {{ form.downvote }}
        </form>

    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```